# Floats to integers in equations

Tags: python-3.x

I need to use values with decimal points in an equation, but when I enter them it doesn't work because of the whole "float" thing.
How can I change this to get an answer?

```
def windowvars(deltP, mu, L, outR, inR):
    v = (deltP/(4.0*mu*L))(outR**2-inR**2)
    print(v)


windowvars(60, 0.000018, 1.0, .5, .5)
```

These are the numbers I need to use.

Answer (score 1):

What result are you attempting to get?

From what I see you are using

```
def windowvars(deltP, mu, L, outR, inR):
    v = (deltP/(4.0*mu**L))*(outR*2-inR*2)
    print("{:.10f}".format(v))
```

As your function,

```
(outR*2-inR*2)
```

This part of your function creates a zero based on your input of 0.5 and 0.5, so is the equation correct?

Comment: oops. No, unfortunately that's not correct, but at this point I'd be happy with even a result of 0! I don't want any more errors